# Why am I getting a segfault, when trying to recursively navigate directories in C?

Tags: c, recursion, dirent.h

This is for a project in my op/sys class.
My end goal is copying a directory recursively.

the function below causes a segfault when it sees a directory.
I'm not using the functions for copying yet.  I'm just trying to get navigation down.
source is the directory I'm navigating and dest is a placeholder for now.

it fails at the arrow when dp is a directory.

```
static void clone(const char* source, const char* dest){
    DIR *dirp;
    struct dirent *dp;
    dirp = opendir(source);
    dp = readdir(dirp);
    while (dp != NULL){
        if (strcmp(dp->d_name, "..") && strcmp(dp->d_name, "."))
        switch (dp->d_type) {
            case DT_DIR:
                printf("dir: %s\n", dp->d_name);
                //saved for making copy
->              clone(dp->d_name, dest);
                break;
            default:
                printf("fil: %s\n", dp->d_name);
                break;
        }
        dp = readdir(dirp);
    }
    closedir(dirp);
}
```

edit:

I hate it when I spend hours on a problem, then ask for help, and immediately get it working.  The answer is posted below.

Comment: I expect that the trouble is you don't check the result of `opendir()`, and as you recurse deeper, you need to prefix more to the names that `readdir()` returns, but I see no evidence of you adding data.  Or you have to use `chdir()` to go down the directory hierarchy, but that is an even more fraught process.  On the whole, then, you need to prefix the names correctly, and check for errors more assiduously.

Comment: Please post the solution as an answer to make it clear that it's solved

Comment: Note: Suggest to change `char rsource[512];` approach.  1) it is very limited 2) It creates a copy at each recursion level.  Instead, at the top, pass in a working buffer of specified size.

Answer (score 0):

I changed it to pass the full path for the next directory, instead of the relative path.

```
static void clone(const char* source, const char* dest){
    DIR *dirp;
    struct dirent *dp;
    dirp = opendir(source);
    dp = readdir(dirp);
    while (dp != NULL){
        char rsource[512];
        strcpy(rsource, source);
        strcat(rsource, "/");
        strcat(rsource, dp->d_name);

        if (strcmp(dp->d_name, "..") && strcmp(dp->d_name, "."))
        switch (dp->d_type) {
            case DT_DIR:
                printf("dir: %s\n", dp->d_name);
                //saved for making copy

                clone(rsource, dest);
                break;
            default:
                printf("fil: %s\n", dp->d_name);
                break;
        }
        dp = readdir(dirp);
    }
    closedir(dirp);
}
```